# How to set up case management for a module and form in CommCare to only update the User Case Data

Tags: commcare

I'm setting up a module and a form in my CommCare application that should only update the User Case data. I've set up the User Case data tab to update the User Case properties that I would like to store. However, I'm not sure if I should configure the case management tab in CommCare to "update or closes a case" or if I should leave that tab as "does not use cases." Is there a correct way to configure the case management tab so CommCare knows I'm only updating the User Case in this module and form? I checked the docs here: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/User+Case but didn't see a specific instruction about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you can leave the Case Management tab as "does not use cases." This controls the cases of the case type you've selected in your module.

The User Case will automatically be loaded into your form when you choose a form that has User Case setup.